# Validating dynamically loaded choices in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, validation, symfony-2.1

I have a choice field type named *sub_choice* in my form whose choices will be dynamically loaded through AJAX depending on the selected value of the parent choice field, named *parent_choice*. Loading the choices works perfectly but I'm encountering a problem when validating the value of the sub_choice upon submission. It gives a "This value is not valid" validation error since the submitted value is not in the choices of the sub_choice field when it was built. So is there a way I can properly validate the submitted value of the sub_choice field? Below is the code for building my form. I'm using Symfony 2.1.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('parent_choice', 'entity', array(
                    'label' => 'Parent Choice',
                    'class' => 'Acme\TestBundle\Entity\ParentChoice'
    ));

    $builder->add('sub_choice', 'choice', array(
                    'label' => 'Sub Choice',
                    'choices' => array(),
                    'virtual' => true
    ));
}
```

Comment: did you have any luck with this?  im stuck on something similar.

Comment: A more recent similar question links to this one, and one of the answers looks pretty good, to do with using a PRE_BIND event to sort out the valid list of options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207476/symfony2-dynamic-form-choices-validation-remove

Comment: here is version with any value accept 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245027/symfony-2-choice-ajax-validation-fix

Answer (score 25):

To do the trick you need to overwrite the `sub_choice` field before submitting the form:

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    ...

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $parentChoice = $event->getData();
        $subChoices = $this->getValidChoicesFor($parentChoice);

        $event->getForm()->add('sub_choice', 'choice', [
            'label'   => 'Sub Choice',
            'choices' => $subChoices,
        ]);
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this answer most completely and directly gives what the question wants: options set dependent on another selected value, without having to messily provide all options to pass validation and then maybe re-setting options later.  This strikes me as the "proper Symfony 2" solution.

Answer (score 3):

this accept any value

```
 $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    if(is_array($data['tags']))$data=array_flip($data['tags']);
    else $data = array();
    $event->getForm()->add('tags', 'tag', [
        'label'   => 'Sub Choice',
        'choices' => $data,
        'mapped'=>false,
        'required'=>false,
        'multiple'=>true,
    ]);
});
```

Comment: That's not a solution that "properly validate the submitted value" (as asked by OP). It just works around validation. What was the point to add this answer months after [Eugene Leonovich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23105434) which already better addressed OP question?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an alternate approach for future readers since I had to do a lot of investigation to get my form working. Here is the breakdown:

1. Adding a "New" option to a dropdown via jquery
2. If "New" is selected display new form field "Custom Option"
3. Submit Form
4. Validate data
5. Save to database

jquery code for twig:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("[name*='[custom_option]']").parent().parent().hide(); // hide on load

        $("[name*='[options]']").append('<option value="new">New</option>'); // add "New" option
        $("[name*='[options]']").trigger("chosen:updated");
    });

    $("[name*='[options]']").change(function() {
        var companyGroup = $("[name*='[options]']").val();

        if (companyGroup == 'new') { // when new option is selected display text box to enter custom option
            $("[name*='[custom_option]']").parent().parent().show();
        } else {
            $("[name*='[custom_option]']").parent().parent().hide();
        }
    });
});

// Here's my Symfony 2.6 form code:
    ->add('options', 'entity', [
    'class'         => 'Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Options',
    'property'      => 'display',
    'empty_value'   => 'Select an Option',
    'mapped'        => true,
    'property_path' => 'options.optionGroup',
    'required' => true,
])
->add('custom_option', 'text', [
    'required' => false,
    'mapped'   => false,
])
```

To handle the form data we need to use the PRE_SUBMIT form event.

```
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
    if (isset($data['options']) && $data['options'] === 'new') {
        $customOption = $data['custom_option'];

        // todo: handle this better on your own
        if (empty($customOption)) {
            $form->addError(new FormError('Please provide a custom option'));
            return;
        }

        // Check for a duplicate option
        $matches = $this->doctrine->getRepository('Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Options')->matchByName([$customOption]);
        if (count($matches) > 0) {
            $form->addError(new FormError('Duplicate option found'));
            return;
        }

        // More validation can be added here

        // Creates new option in DB
        $newOption = $this->optionsService->createOption($customOption); // return object after persist and flush in service
        $data['options'] = $newOption->getOptionId();
        $event->setData($data);
    }
});
```

Let me know if ya'll have any questions or concerns. I know this might not be the best solution but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

you cannot not build the sub_choice validation because during you config its validator you don't know which values are valid (values depend on value of parent_choice).

What you can do is to resolve parent_choice into entity before you make new YourFormType() in your controller.
Then you can get all the possible values for sub_choice and provide them over the form constructor - new YourFormType($subChoice).

In YourFormType you have to add __construct method like this one:

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $subChoice = array();

public function __construct(array $subChoice)
{
    $this->subChoice = $subChoice;
}
```

and use provided values in form add:

```
$builder->add('sub_choice', 'choice', array(
                'label' => 'Sub Choice',
                'choices' => $this->subChoice,
                'virtual' => true
));
```

Answer (score -6):

Suppose for sub choices you have id's right ? 
Create and empty array with a certain number of values and give it as a choice

`$indexedArray = [];
        for ($i=0; $i<999; $i++){
            $indexedArray[$i]= '';
        }`

then `'choices'  => $indexedArray,` :)