# Symfony2 - Dynamic form choices - validation remove

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have a drop down form element.  Initially it starts out empty but it is populated with values via javascript after the user has made some interactions.  Thats all working ok.  However when I submit it always returns a validation error `This value is not valid.`.

If I add the items to the choices list in the form code it will validate OK however I am trying to populate it dynamically and pre adding the items to the choices list is not going to work.

The problem I think is because the form is validating against an empty list of items.  I don't want it to validate against a list at all.  I have set validation required to false.  I switched the chocie type to text and that always passes validation.

**This will only validate against empty rows or items added to choice list**

```
$builder->add('verified_city', 'choice', array(
  'required' =>  false
));
```

Similar question here that was not answered.
[Validating dynamically loaded choices in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946461/validating-dynamically-loaded-choices-in-symfony-2)

Say you don't know what all the available choices are.  It could be loaded in from a external web source?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after much time messing around trying to find it. You basically need to add a `PRE_BIND` listener.  You add some extra choices just before you bind the values ready for validation.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;


public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

  // .. create form code at the top

    $ff = $builder->getFormFactory();

    // function to add 'template' choice field dynamically
    $func = function (FormEvent $e) use ($ff) {
      $data = $e->getData();
      $form = $e->getForm();
      if ($form->has('verified_city')) {
        $form->remove('verified_city');
      }


      // this helps determine what the list of available cities are that we can use
      if ($data instanceof  \Portal\PriceWatchBundle\Entity\PriceWatch) {
        $country = ($data->getVerifiedCountry()) ? $data->getVerifiedCountry() : null;
      }
      else{
        $country = $data['verified_country'];
      }

      // here u can populate choices in a manner u do it in loadChoices use your service in here
      $choices = array('', '','Manchester' => 'Manchester', 'Leeds' => 'Leeds');

      #if (/* some conditions etc */)
      #{
      #  $choices = array('3' => '3', '4' => '4');
      #}
      $form->add($ff->createNamed('verified_city', 'choice', null, compact('choices')));
    };

    // Register the function above as EventListener on PreSet and PreBind

    // This is called when form first init - not needed in this example
    #$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $func); 

    // called just before validation 
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_BIND, $func);  

}
```

Comment: I'm running the same problem and I use DataTransformer to fix it but without success so I'll use this approach. Since the data is built in a controller by using a AJAX call, how I can populate the `$choices` array? Any advice?

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  More detailed example of this approach (albeit using PRE_SUBMIT): http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-4-dependent-forms/

Comment: And subtly different example (secondary field only added to form after primary field is submitted, using POST_SUBMIT) from the Symfony docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

Answer (score 0):

The validation is handled by the Validator component: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html.

The `required` option in the Form layer is used to control the HTML5 `required` attribute, so it won't change anything for you, and that is normal.

What you should do here is to configure the Validation layer according to the documentation linked above.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean by configure validation layer?

Comment: I have read the documentation and tried adding a validation with min - max constraints of 0 and 255 and it doesnt work.  It still wants only options from a pre-set list.

Comment: Ok, so I guess this may help you: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html.

Comment: i just want to disable the validation that seems like going around the houses and making it more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Found a better solution which I posted here: [Disable backend validation for choice field in Symfony 2 Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706719/disable-backend-validation-for-choice-field-in-symfony-2-type/31831869#31831869)

### Old answer:

Just spent a few hours dealing with that problem. This choice - type is really annoying. My solution is similar to yours, maybe a little shorter. Of course it's a hack but what can you do...

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('place', 'choice'); //don't validate that

    //... more form fields

   //before submit remove the field and set the submitted choice as
   //"static" choices to make "ChoiceToValueTransformer" happy
   $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        if ($form->has('place')) {
            $form->remove('place');
        }

        $form->add('place', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array($data['place']=>'Whatever'),
        ));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside `buildForm` method in your form type class so that you can validate an input field value rather a choice from a select field value;

```
$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,

    function (FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if ($form->has('verified_city')) {
            $form->remove('verified_city');
            $form->add(
                'verified_city', 
                'text', 
                ['required' => false]
            )
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Update in Validations.yml**

Kindly update the Validation.yml file in the below format : setting the group names in the each field

```
 
         password:
            - NotBlank: { message: Please enter password ,groups: [Default]}


Update in Form Type
  
 /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'RegistrationBundle\Entity\sf_members',
             'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form){

   $data = $form->getData();

   $member_id =  $data->getMemberId();
```

// Block of code; 
 // starts Here :

`if( condition == 'edit profile') {
                                return array('edit');  
                          } else                             
                          {
                              return array('Default');  
                          }

         },`

**Update in Entity**

   `/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="text")
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/(?i)^(?=.[a-zA-Z])(?=.\d).{8,}$/",
     *     match=true,
     *     message="Your password must be at least 8 characters, including at least one number and one letter",
     *     groups={"Default","edit"}
     * )
     */

    private $password;`