# Allow the addition of new values to a ChoiceType Field

Tags: symfony, jquery-select2, symfony2-forms

I use `Form Component` and have a [ChoiceType field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) on the form which is rendered to a select field.
On the client-side I use [select2 plugin](http://select2.github.io/) which initializes a select with `tags: true` allowing the addition of new values to it.
But if I add a new value then a validation on the server fails with an error

> This value is not valid.

because the new value isn't in the choice list.

Is there a way to allow the addition of new values to a `ChoiceType field`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is in a choice transformer, which erases values that don't exist in a choice list.
[The workaround with disabling the transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31831869/3141596) helped me:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('choiceField', 'choice', ['choices' => $someList]);

    // more fields...

    $builder->get('choiceField')->resetViewTransformers();
}
```

Comment: Guys does this suggestion worked for you? 
I tried to implement it in a SonataAdmin project but seems doing nothing...

$formMapper->add('serviceType', ChoiceType::class)->get('serviceType')->resetViewTransformers()

Answer (score 9):

Here's an example code in case someone needs this for EntityType instead of the ChoiceType. Add this to your FormType:

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Category;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();

    if (!$data) {
        return;
    }

    $categoryId = $data['category'];

    // Do nothing if the category with the given ID exists
    if ($this->em->getRepository(Category::class)->find($categoryId)) {
        return;
    }

    // Create the new category
    $category = new Category();
    $category->setName($categoryId);
    $this->em->persist($category);
    $this->em->flush();

    $data['category'] = $category->getId();
    $event->setData($data);
});
```

Comment: Working on Symfony4. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not.

You should implement this manually by either:

- using the select2 events to create the new choice via ajax
- catching the posted options before validating the form, and add it to the options list